# How can I use REGEX to test for currency formats

Tags: regex

How can you create a regular expression that checks if a user input matches characters formally found in a currency syntax? (number, period/decimal place, comma, or dollar sign?).

The following can find all characters listed above except for the dollar sign, any idea how to properly structure this?

```
/([0-9.,])/g
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex I use for currency validation is as follows:

```
^(\$)?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2})(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$|^(\$)?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2})(\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$|^(0)?(\.\d{2})?$|^(\$0)?(\.\d{2})?$|^$
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com/) is a great website for testing and reviewing these strings (perhaps you could make a regex string that's less of a beast!)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to test the characters? In that case

```
[0-9,.$]+
```

will suffice.  Or are you testing for the format `$1,123,123.12` with the correct placements of commas and everything?

In that case you would need something more like

```
(\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:.\d{2})?)
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

*You* need to define what you want your regex to match, more formally than "matches characters formally found in a currency syntax". We don't know which currencies you're interested in. We don't know how strict you need it to be.

Maybe you'll come up with something like:

> These elements must come in this order:
>
> - A currency symbol ('£', '€' or '$')  (your requirement might specify more currencies)
> - 1 or more numeric digits
> - A period or a comma
> - Exactly two numeric digits

Once you have a specification like that, it's easy to translate into a regular expression:

```
[£€$]    // one of these chars.
\d+      // '+' means 'one or more'
[.,]    // '[]' means 'any one of these'. 
\d\d     // Two digits. Could also be written as '\d{2}'
```

Or concatenated together:

```
[£€$]\d+[.,]\d\d
```

If you've learned about escaping special characters like `$` and `.`, you may be surprised not to see it done here. Within `[]`, they lose their special meaning.

(There are dialects of regex -- check the documentation for whatever implementation you're using)

Your requirements may be different though. The example I've given doesn't match:

- `$  12.00`
- `$12`
- `USD12`
- `¥200.00`
- `25¢`
- `$0.00005`
- `20 μBTC`
- `44 dollars`
- `£1/19/11¾d` ("one pound, nineteen shillings and elevenpence three farthings")

Work out your requirement, then write your code to meet it.

Comment: You don't need to escape special characters (`$`, `.`) in character classes.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks, I was just verifying that when you commented. Have fixed.

Answer (score -1):

you should set \ before special chars, also you should set star(0+) or plus(1+) for match full currency chars, for example:

```
/([0-9\.,]*)/g
```

or for real price how 200,00 where all time exist 2 symbols after comma:

```
/(([0-9]+)(\.|,)([0-9]){2})/g
```

Comment: Nope, you don't need to escape periods (or asterisks, questionmarks, etc)  when they are within square brackets.  Try it: `echo foo | grep '[.]'` vs `echo foo. | grep '[.]'`. Also, your regex would match a zero length string, or a lone comma.

Comment: @ghoti, actually yes, but it was very simplify example